# Get user name with Apache CXF 2.4 JAX-RS and Spring Security 3.2

Tags: java, junit, spring-security, jax-rs, cxf

I get the user name in my JAX-RS resource with `SecurityContextHolder` and that works:

```
@Path("/myresource")
public class MyResoure {

     @Get
     public String getUserName() {
          return SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName();
     }
}
```

But I want to inject the SecurityContext into a class field (to write JUnit tests). I tried some documented ways:

With `javax.ws.rs.core.SecurityContext` I get a `NullPointerException`, because the `securityContext` is always `null`.

```
@Path("/myresource")
public class MyResoure {

    @Context
    private javax.ws.rs.core.SecurityContext securityContext;

    @Get
    public String getUserName() {
        return securityContext.getUserPrincipal().getName();
    }
}
```

With `org.apache.cxf.security.SecurityContext` (see [Apache CXF documentation](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-and-jax-ws.html#JAX-RSandJAX-WS-Dealingwithcontexts)) I get a `NullPointerException`, because the `securityContext.getUserPrincipal()` is always `null`.

```
@Path("/myresource")
public class MyResoure {

    @Context
    private org.apache.cxf.security.SecurityContext securityContext;

    @Get
    public String getUserName() {
        return securityContext.getUserPrincipal().getName();
    }
}
```

With `org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.ext.MessageContext` (see [Apache CXF documentation](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-and-jax-ws.html#JAX-RSandJAX-WS-Dealingwithcontexts)) I get a `NullPointerException`, because the `messageContext.getSecurityContext().getUserPrincipal()` is always `null`.

```
@Path("/myresource")
public class MyResoure {

    @Context
    private org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.ext.MessageContext messageContext;

    @Get
    public String getUserName() {
        return messageContext.getSecurityContext().getUserPrincipal().getName();
    }
}
```

With `javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest` I get a `NullPointerException`, because the `httpServletRequest.getUserPrincipal()` is always `null`.

```
@Path("/myresource")
public class MyResoure {

    @Context
    private javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest;

    @Get
    public String getUserName() {
        return httpServletRequest.getUserPrincipal().getName();
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried investigating as to how user name gets set in SecurityContext ?  You could create an Authentication object, create SecurityContext and then set the SecurityContext in thread locale via SecurityContextHolder at Junit setup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the user name with

- `javax.ws.rs.core.SecurityContext`,
- `org.apache.cxf.security.SecurityContext`,
- `org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.ext.MessageContext` or
- `javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest`

I had to add the `SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter` to my `springSecurityFilterChain`.

Spring configuration:

```
<bean id="springSecurityFilterChain" class="org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy">
    <security:filter-chain-map path-type="ant">
        <security:filter-chain pattern="/**" filters="securityContextPersistenceFilter,authenticationProcessingFilter,securityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter,anonymousProcessingFilter,exceptionTranslationFilter,filterSecurityInterceptor" />
    </security:filter-chain-map>
</bean>
```

With Security Namespace Configuration or [Java Configuration](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.8.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#jc) the filter is added by default, see [Spring Security documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.8.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#nsa-web):

> - **servlet-api-provision** Provides versions of HttpServletRequest security methods such as isUserInRole() and getPrincipal() which are implemented by  adding a SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter bean to the stack. Defaults to true.

Answer (score 1):

I found some solutions for my JUnit problem:

- Setting `SecurityContext` in `SecurityContextHolder` (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/5703170)

  JUnit test code:

  ```
  public class MyResourceTest {

      private SecurityContext securityContextMock = mock(SecurityContext.class);

      @Before
      public void setUp() {
          SecurityContextHolder.setContext(securityContextMock);
      }

      @After
      public void tearDown() {
          SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
      }
  }
  ```
- Wrapping `SecurityContextHolder` (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/5702970)

  Wrapper code:

  ```
  public class MySecurityContextHolder {
      public SecurityContext getContext() {
          return SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
      }
  }
  ```

  Resource code:

  ```
  @Path("/myresource")
  public MyResource {

      private MySecurityContextHolder mySecurityContextHolder;

      @Get
      public String getUserName() {
           return mySecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName();
      }
  }
  ```
- Using SecurityContextHolderStrategy (see [SEC-1188](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SEC-1188))

  Spring configuration:

  ```
  <bean id="myResource" class="MyResource">
      <property name="securityContextHolderStrategy" >
          <bean class="org.springframework.security.context.SecurityContextHolder" factory-method="getContexHolderStrategy">
          </bean>
      </property>
  </bean>
  ```

  Resource code:

  ```
  @Path("/myresource")
  public MyResource {

      private SecurityContextHolderStrategy securityContextHolderStrategy;

      @Get
      public String getUserName() {
           return securityContextHolderStrategy.getContext().getAuthentication().getName();
      }
  }
  ```
- Using PowerMock (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/5703197/5277820)