# How to get username in jax-rs cxf based non-spring application?

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, cxf

I am trying to use org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.ext.MessageContext to get the username. However, it returns null all the time. Do I need to set something in my web.xml ?

```
@Context
private MessageContext myContext;
HttpServletRequest request = myContext.getHttpServletRequest();
String user = (String)request.getRemoteUser();
```

Comment: this can help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32796368/get-user-name-with-apache-cxf-2-4-jax-rs-and-spring-security-3-2

Comment: thanks ! it worked